# does React-native-maps support windows, if not, which library can I use for using maps in my windows app by using React-Native

Tags: windows, react-native, react-native-maps, windows-application-packaging

I am searching if I can use React-Native to build a windows application, where I want to use a map(I prefer Google Maps) to display some information.

I checked the React-Native-Maps library, and it only supports IOS and Android.

Does anyone know if it supports windows app? if not, are there other options?

Thanks
[image: https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is currently only one solution: use React+Electron coding again :)